# IPC::Run - Detection of premature child exit and closed pipes

Tags: perl, fork, ipc

I would like to use IPC::Run to communicate with child via child's STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR (start, pump, finish).  It seems to work.

I would like to know how to detect

- premature child exit (e.g. caused by errors)
- pipes closed by the child

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pump` throws a `die` on errors, or writes its message to `STDERR` if "*called after all harnessed activities have completed*." See right before [ROUTINES](http://search.cpan.org/%7Etoddr/IPC-Run-0.96/lib/IPC/Run.pm#ROUTINES) section and `pump` itself. The second case can come about if the child exited. So wrap the `pump` call in `eval`, and also convert warnings to `die` to catch both cases

```
if ($talk_to_child) 
{
    eval {
        local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub { die "pump WARNING: @_" };
        pump $harness;
    };
    if ($@) { 
        print $@;
        $talk_to_child = 0;
    }; 
}
# ... and eval {} for finish()
```

But this alone won't cut it: when a parent tries to write to a child that exited it gets a `SIGPIPE`, which outright terminates the process. The same goes when a child closes streams and the parent attempts to write. So also install a signal handler for `SIGPIPE`

```
$SIG{PIPE} = sub { 
    say "$_[0]: $!";
    $talk_to_child = 0;  # global
};
```

so that the parent survives the `SIGPIPE`. Consider [local](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Temporary-Values-via-local())-izing the change to the global [%SIG](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables) by doing `local $SIG{PIPE} = ...` instead, a good practice even just on general principle. On the other hand, there's good sense in globally handling a signal that can terminate you out of blue (even in cases where the handler may decide to exit).

The `eval` is still needed even as `$SIG{PIPE}` is handled since `pump` throws, too.

These together take care of all tests I came up with, practically as they stand. Still, some processing in the handler and in `eval` is needed to distinguish cases of interest if that is wanted.

If this adds up to too much another way is to check before each call.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40662962/4653379) for one-line checks (wrapped in subs) of: (1) whether a child is running, using `result`, and (2) whether "*there are open I/O channels or active processes*", using `pumpable`.

I think that you want both, and also throw in the `SIGPIPE` handler. That should cover it.

I cannot be more specific here since the question doesn't provide specifics.

Comment: Nice catch of `SIGPIPE`. I think that was what I was missing :)

Comment: @HåkonHægland  Right, the `SIGPIPE` is the show stopper.  But this is still complicated. It may be simpler to check before each call using a combination of `result` and `pumpable` (plus `SIGPIPE` handler).

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip  I updated the answer with a comment on checking directly using `result` + `pumpable` (+ `SIGPIPE` handler). I also edited a few comments for accuracy. I confirmed in my tests that the main approach in the answer does handle all cases, practically as it stands.    Let us know how it works for you. The answer by @Håkon also got updated.

Comment: Yes this is indeed complictated and also interesting. So another thing is that if we get SIGPIPE, and the child has turned off autoflush for its STDOUT (see my `child2.pl` example) the output from the child is simply lost. In this case, I think we also need to conect the child to a pseudo terminal, in order to make it turn on autoflushing again.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Thanks to @zdim for reminding me to check the `SIGPIPE` signal. Here is an update of my answer that also checks `SIGPIPE`:

I did a simple test using `start`, `pump`, and `finish`. Here is the main script `p.pl` that I used:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use IPC::Run;

my $child_in;
my $child_out;
my $child_err;
my $child_name = shift;

my $harness = eval {
    IPC::Run::start [ $child_name ], \$child_in, \$child_out, \$child_err;
};
if ( $@ ) {
    chomp $@;
    die "Caught exception: '$@'";
}
for (1..2) {
    $child_in = "Joe$_\n";
    say "Parent sleeping for 1 second..";
    sleep 1;
    eval {
        local $SIG{PIPE} = sub { 
            die "Parent received SIGPIPE. "
              . "Child is either dead or has closed its input pipe\n";
        };
        say "Sending data to child..";
        my $result = $harness->pump;
        say "IPC::Run::pump() returned: ", $result ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";
    };
    if ( $@ ) {
        chomp $@;
        say "IPC::Run::pump() failed: '$@'";
        last;
    }
    say "\$child_in = '$child_in'";
    say "\$child_out = '$child_out'";
}
say "Finishing harness..";
my $res = eval {
    local $SIG{PIPE} = sub { 
        die "Parent received SIGPIPE. "
          . "Child is either dead or has closed its input pipe\n";
    };
    $harness->finish;
};
if ( $@ ) {
    chomp $@;
    die "IPC::Run::finish() failed: '$@'\n";
}
printf "IPC::Run::finish() returned: '%s'\n", $res ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";
chomp $child_out;
say "STDOUT from child: '$child_out'";
chomp $child_err;
say "STDERR from child: '$child_err'";
say "Child returned exit code: ", $harness->result;
say "Parent exited normally.."
```

I used three different child scripts:

**child.pl**:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl    
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $reply = <STDIN>;
chomp $reply;
say "Hello $reply";
my $reply2 = <STDIN>;
chomp $reply2;
say "Got second reply: $reply2";
exit 0;
```

and output:

```
$ p.pl child.pl
Parent sleeping for 1 second..
Sending data to child..
IPC::Run::pump() returned: TRUE
$child_in = ''
$child_out = ''
Parent sleeping for 1 second..
Sending data to child..
IPC::Run::pump() returned: TRUE
$child_in = ''
$child_out = ''
Finishing harness..
IPC::Run::finish() returned: 'TRUE'
STDOUT from child: 'Hello Joe1
Got second reply: Joe2'
STDERR from child: ''
Child returned exit code: 
Parent exited normally..
```

**child2.pl**:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $reply = <STDIN>;
chomp $reply;
say "Hello $reply";
die "Child exception\n";
```

and output:

```
$ p.pl child2.pl
Parent sleeping for 1 second..
Sending data to child..
IPC::Run::pump() returned: TRUE
$child_in = ''
$child_out = ''
Parent sleeping for 1 second..
Sending data to child..
IPC::Run::pump() failed: 'Parent received SIGPIPE. Child is either dead or has closed its input pipe'
Finishing harness..
IPC::Run::finish() failed: 'Parent received SIGPIPE. Child is either dead or has closed its input pipe'
```

**child3.pl**:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

close \*STDIN;
close \*STDOUT;
close \*STDERR;
sleep 5;
exit 2;
```

and output:

```
$ p.pl child3.pl 
Parent sleeping for 1 second..
Sending data to child..
IPC::Run::pump() failed: 'ack Parent received SIGPIPE. Child is either dead or has closed its input pipe'
Finishing harness..
IPC::Run::finish() failed: 'Parent received SIGPIPE. Child is either dead or has closed its input pipe'
```

So for these tests, it seems that the `SIGPIPE` signal can be used to check if a child is a alive or has closed its input pipe. Note that if you try to call `pump()` after a child has exited, the previous output from the child is lost, see the `child2.pl` example.

Comment: I am interested in case of **long** running child with big number of "command-response" sequences. I would like to avoid pushing commands to child with closed STDIN or pumping replies from child with closed STDOUT.